# Extracting file path from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have log lines that looks something like this

```
Saving stack trace for 19254 to D:\Users\tempdir\buildTmp\tmp8o258\testgroupnamelinux_stack_trace.txt
Copy Dir: D:\Users\tempdir\buildTmp\tmp8fd7h5ao\build -> D:\Users\tempdir\buildTmp\tmpj7xj7ydn\build
['D:\\something\\branchname\\somewhere\\blablabla.txt'] have changes under D:\something\branchname\somewhere
```

I want to replace the file paths with the word `filepath` to normalize my data. The end result should look something like this

```
Saving stack trace for 19254 to filepath
Copy Dir: filepath -> filepath
['filepath'] have changes under filepath
```

I am trying to find a way regex or something else, that might help me do this for an entire dataset.

Comment: What code have you tried/is generating this output? If it is not being printed by you, then I don't think you can do it without modifying the packages generating this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted that your files will be following a specific known pattern, you could do something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'D\:.*.txt')
# Something that starts with D: and ends with .txt, anything in between
```

Then you could call `.sub(pattern, str)`

Comment: The data can have different file extensions but I can create a list of all the distinct file extensions and then repeat this process for all. Thanks

Comment: You don't even need to do this separately, you could create a set of extensions, eg `[.txt|.jpg|.csv|]` white the pipes indicate 'or'. That expression would replace `.txt` in my original answer.

Comment: That's even better.